# I added a Lightning component in Vf page but it is showing the component two times in same page

Tags: lightning-aura-components

The problem is with showHeader="false" on VF page

when I removed showHeader="false" it is working. But I don't want to display header.

My Page :

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" >
    <apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />
    <div id="lightning" />

     <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:AccountInfoApp", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("c:AccountInfoComponent",
          { label : "" },
          "lightning",
          function(cmp) {
            // do some stuff
          });
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Aura application code :

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp"> 
    <aura:dependency resource="c:AccountInfoComponent"/>
</aura:application>
```

Controller:

```
public class AccountInformation 
{
   @AuraEnabled

   public static List<Account> getAccounts() 
{

      return [SELECT Id, name, industry,website from Account limit 1];


   }   
}
```

Component:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th> NAME  </th>
                    <th>PHONE </th>
                    <th>Website</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <aura:iteration var="cell" items="{!v.accountRows}">
                    <tr>

                        <td> {!cell.Name}  </td>
                        <td>{!cell.Phone}</td>
                        <td>{!cell.Website}</td>
                    </tr>
                </aura:iteration>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: can you post code of your AccountInfoApp, it seems like you have added c:AccountInfoComponent into that app as well.

Comment: My App :<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:AccountInfoComponent"/>
</aura:application>

Comment: strange same code is working for me. can you test it with tutorial https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm? by creating <aura:dependency resource="ui:button"/>

Comment: the example is working for me. May be there is something wrong with my component.

Comment: yah. it seems like. update question with your component code as well.

Comment: The problem is with <apex:page standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false"  > when I removed showHeader="false" it is working Is there any work around I dont want to display header.

Comment: but it worked for me in that way.

Comment: Ugh I don't understand why it is happening.  But anyways thanks for your help Himanshu

Comment: You are using a very generic div id - 'lightning' rename the div and try again.

Comment: @CasparHarmer i don't think that is the issue because tutorial code is working with lightning div it is not reserved.

Comment: @Anjali let me test with your code

Comment: Sure.. @Himanshu